# Vue generate form json data truncate label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-formulate

I have vueformulate implemented in my project and I am generating the form from json data. I need to implement truncate filter - for example 80 characters, with read more/less for the label. Data is dynamic so i cant change label in this object array. Here's my code. Any idea?

```js
Vue.use(VueFormulate)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
        data: [
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'first',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        },
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'second',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        },
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'third',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.formulate-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.formulate-input-error {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@braid/vue-formulate@2.4.1/dist/formulate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <formulate-form>
        <formulate-input
            v-for="item in data"
            :key="item.name"
            v-bind="item"
        />
      </formulate-form>
</div>
```

[image: default label length is truncated to 80 characters, but you can click read more and see full text]

[image: full text visible after click read more button]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  computed property from `data` with label truncated:

```
computed: {
  truncated() {
    return this.data.map(({ label, ...rest }) => ({ label: label.slice(0, 80), ...rest }));
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.use(VueFormulate)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
        data: [
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'first',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        },
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'second',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        },
        {
          validation: "accepted",
          type: 'checkbox',
          name: 'third',
          label: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    truncated() {
      return this.data.map(({ label, ...rest }) => ({ label: label.slice(0, 
 80), ...rest }));
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.formulate-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.formulate-input-error {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@braid/vue-formulate@2.4.1/dist/formulate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <formulate-form>
        <formulate-input
            v-for="item in truncated"
            :key="item.name"
            v-bind="item"
        />
      </formulate-form>
</div>
```

Comment: but how to create ream more/less with this solution?

Comment: @Marek Not sure I understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe a daigram or schreenshot of your desired solution would be helpful here.

Comment: @Psidom just added images to my question.  The main goal is you have truncated text in label, but there is read more button, when you click it, full label text should be visible.